# SOAP Request to web service

Tags: soap, request

I have a web application which calls an external party web service. I want to send a SOAP request to this external party. Please tell me how I can do this.

I am using ASP.net with C#

```
UsernameToken userToken = new UsernameToken(strUserName, strPWD, PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
SoapContext requestContext = TPService.RequestSoapContext;
requestContext.Security.Tokens.Add(userToken);
TPService.Timeout = 100000000;
requestContext.Security.Timestamp.TtlInSeconds = 60;


List<employeeLeave> ObjCrewLeavesList= new List<employeeLeave>();
employeeLeavesRS ObjcrewLeaveRS = TPService.getEmployeeLeaves(ObjLeaveRQ);
```

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried? And which language you are using?

Comment: I am using ASP.net with C# ===================================

UsernameToken userToken = new UsernameToken(strUserName, strPWD, PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
SoapContext requestContext = TPService.RequestSoapContext;
requestContext.Security.Tokens.Add(userToken);
TPService.Timeout = 100000000;
requestContext.Security.Timestamp.TtlInSeconds = 60;
          

List<employeeLeave> ObjCrewLeavesList= new List<employeeLeave>();
employeeLeavesRS ObjcrewLeaveRS = TPService.getEmployeeLeaves(ObjLeaveRQ);